# detail UIViewController in UISplitViewController doesn't get resized correctly when rotating the device

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I've done everything programmatically. When I rotate the device from landscape to portrait though, the detail VC remains looking quadratic. It doesn't get scaled up.

I changed the backgroundColor of the view to yellow. When it rotates, then I see a yellow cube and above it about 300 points or so which are gray. The view controller doesnt resize it's view correctly.

I've set all the autoresizing masks:

detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Doesn't help. The view remains quadratic like it was in landscape mode, even when rotated to portrait. Then it should actually be a lot higher.

What else can cause this bad behavior? I looked at all those settings from an apple example in Interface Builder and my programmatic creation recreates that exactly as far as I can tell. Something must be missing. Probably some autoresize mask missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the quadratic details view in the simulator (4.1) quite often, even in Apple's example (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775) but it's not 100% reproducable. Switch orientation forth and back and it is okay. I have never seen the issue on the real device.

One more guess: are all your view controller (the split view itself, the root controller and all detail views) overriding shouldAutoRotateToOrientation and return YES in there?

René